Does a Language Accepted by a Non-deterministic Turing Machine with Zero Errors Necessarily Belong to Class R
It is said that a non-deterministic Turing machine M accepts a language L with m errors if and only if:

For every x in language L, M does not accept x in at most m calculation routes.
for every x that does not belong to the language L, M does not reject x at most m calculation routes/

Prove or disprove
If there is a non-deterministic Turing machine that accepts a language L with 0 errors i.e. m=0 then the language L belongs to R.
my attempt:
the statement is true.
If  M accepts 
L with zero errors, for any string 
x in . L, all paths in . M must accept 
x (since there are zero non-accepting paths for these strings).
For any string 
x not in 
L, all paths in 
M must reject 
x (since there are zero non-rejecting paths for these strings).
Construction of a Deterministic Simulator:
Given that a non-deterministic machine 
M has the aforementioned behavior for  = 0
m=0, one can simulate . M deterministically by following the computation paths. Since we know . M makes no errors, any non-deterministic choice that leads towards acceptance can be deterministically chosen if
. x is in . L, and similarly for rejection if . x is not in  L.
A deterministic Turing machine can be designed to simulate . M and decide  ,L. This machine will effectively follow the guaranteed paths (acceptance paths for strings in , L and rejection paths for strings not in 
L).
